# I have installed code::Blocks IDE but unable to run "Hello world" program

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am writing my first C++ code today. I have installed the code::Blocks IDE, but I'm unable to run a "Hello world" program. I am getting the below error message in the Build Log:

> Checking for existence: C:\Users\saira\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\CodeBlocks\sample.exe

I am using <kbd>F9</kbd> to build and run the program, which is named as `sample.cpp`, but I am unable to see the output of the code. Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Do we need to setup path for C++?

Comment: Why are you trying to building your project into the folder where Windows' Start Menu stores its entries? It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Use Settings to set your code blocks project directory to something like `C:\\Users\\saira\\cbprojects` (or whatever you like, but don't put it below `%AppData%` which is generally considered a hidden directory by default). I don't like to type, so I just use `C:\\Users\\me\cb`.

Comment: Have you installed the compiler? (suggested installer file: codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe, about 179 Mb)